# What is $cacheFactory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can find absolutely no information on what exactly `$cacheFactory` is and how it can be useful in your application.

The Angular Documentation says

> **"Factory that constructs cache objects and gives access to them."** -- [$cacheFactory](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24cacheFactory)

Well, that wasn't at all helpful, what does that mean? There doesn't seem to be anything on Google either.

Can someone please explain **What it is** & **When can it be useful**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Google Search for "Angular $cacheFactory" yields  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$cacheFactory as the first search result.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, the links already in my question...

Comment: @Connor -- This link was posted in the discussion of the Angular Docs, it's a bit better, provides more examples: http://pseudobry.com/power-up-%24http.html

Comment: If you know what a cache is, you should understand the statement of what the CacheFactory is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh the $cacheFactory is simple as i understand it :

If you have a request to retrieve constant data for example like a list of cities.

It's not a good pattern to get this list from the server each time the user go on a form where he has to select a city !

So you have to cache this list. The cacheFactory is done for that !

If you're using $http instead of $resource you can enbale the cache just like that :

```
$http.get('myUrl', { cache: true })
```

Comment: Is there a way to only cache the first X amount of requests? This is probably better suited for a new question, but I figure I'd ask

Comment: Yes, you define "capacity" then it will turn into an LRU cache

Comment: Oh @NilsLarson it's true you can pass a size value to the $cacheFactory better tymeJV and simpler