# How angular $cacheFactory works?

Tags: angularjs

I am going to use angualr $cacheFactory.

I want to understand angular **$cacheFactory** Life cycle

e.g. where is data actually save and how retrieve/update data.

Comment: Have you done any searching from internet?

Comment: Yes, i did, but did not found anything very promising.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is $cacheFactory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964411/what-is-cachefactory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you ask a question about what $cacheFactory is you will have to understand what cache is in general.

**Well what is cache?**

The purpose of cache is to save data temporary to get faster access to it. 
See this url for futher explaination: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)

If you understand this you can use $cacheFactory.

**How to use $cacheFactory?**

I've found a lot of tutorials all around the internet, but I picket the one from the angularjs website.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory

All the methods you need to know to use $cacheFactory are described in here. Parts like storing data to the cache, pull it from the cache and methods to clear the whole cache.

Hope this helped enough.